# HTTP Range Header Request for Parts of PDF Files

Tags: http, header, range

I am using the HTTP Range header in an attempt to extract specific bytes from a PDF file. The server from which I am making the request contains an 'Accept-Ranges: Bytes' response header indicating that this ought to be possible. It is possible for me to supply a request header of 'Range: bytes=0-100' and thereafter to receive a 206 Partial Response as would be expected.

However, when I make a request which does not start at byte offset 0 the server fails to respond at all. That is, if I send a request header of, for example, 'Range: bytes=100-200' the server does not respond at all.

Can anyone offer any advice as to why this happens, and as to how I might resolve the problem?

Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Comment: Only the `Range` is not sufficient. You also need to send `If-Range` (or `If-Match`) along so that the server can verify if you're really requesting exactly the same file version as currently in server's data storage. Did you do that? Normally, the server would return a 400 or 412 error back on its absence, but as it apparently didn't do that it's somewhat stabbing in the dark (although your "server does not respond at all" statement is somewhat ambiguous; maybe you actually meant that the response body is empty and you didn't look at status). Is the server maintained by you or a 3rd party?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

I have tried using 'If-Range' but the same problem results in that the server fails to respond.

I have been able to successfully take byte ranges which do not begin at a 0 offset from other servers.

This does seem really strange, especially considering that the website is advertising that it does 'Accept-Ranges: Bytes'.

Comment: I have tried downloading the PDF file using Internet Explorer, and it does not have an option to pause the download which suggests that Internet Explorer too is having trouble using range headers to pause and resume downloading.

Comment: Apparently the server has range requests badly implemented. If it's under your control, ask a question about that instead. If it's a 3rd party one, report problem to site admins.